# How to Send email with html templates in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, email, templates

i want to try simple email sent like in php but i get templates based email sending in Laravel 5 ??

```
`$to      = Session::get('email');
 $subject = 'Order confirmation';
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: Test <rajdipvekriya1992@gmail.com>"; 
 $message = 'test body';
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`
```

but i want get templates based body html pass $message like to

```
 $body = $this->load-
 >view('admin/email_template/test_template',$data,TRUE);
 $this->email->message($body);
 $this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Mail::send like this

```
\Mail::send('view', $data, function ($message)
{
    $message->subject('Email Subject');
    $message->from('acb@example.com');
    $message->to('xyz@example.com');
});
```

and create view.blade.php, write in laravel blade.

Comment: Perfect answer.if you add some more emails. i.e
    $emails =array('test@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com')
     \Mail::send('view', $data, function ($message)use($emails)
    {
        $message->subject('Email Subject');
        $message->from('acb@example.com');
        $message->to($emails);
    });

Answer (score 0):

create a Mailable class with make command

```
php artisan make:mail
```

then write your code  in handle method

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
  return $this->view('emails.complaint-reply')
        ->subject('Cotint Group')
        ->with(['complaint'=>$this->complaint]);
}
```

And in `emails.complaint-reply.blade.php` file  write down your **HTML template**

Answer (score 0):

I think Mail::raw is what you need:

```
Mail::raw('Text to e-mail', function($message)
{
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');
    $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

Mail::send('email.relatorlead', ['data' => $message], function ($m) use ($message) {
    $m->from('no-reply@twostructureshomes.com', 'Two Structures Homes');
    $m->to('nikunj@whitelabeliq.com');
    $m->subject('Realtor Registration Lead From ' . $message['firstname']);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

have a look to this code, this will surely help you.

```
<?php
   $to = "somebody@example.com";
   $subject = "My subject";
   $txt = "Hello world!";
   $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
   "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
   mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please post a short description of what you are trying to accomplish with this snippet and how exactly is it helpful. Thanks.